# How can I transfer ownership of a Google App Engine app to another person?

Tags: google-app-engine

A long time ago, I created a free Google App for a client on appengine.google.com (http://imitatorgwt.appspot.com).

Now my client wants more computing power - which requires to enable billing. But, I want to let my client pay for the app.

When I tried to enable billing through my Google account, I was asked to give my personal details.

How can I transfer the ownership of the app to my client, so that he will be able to do the billing without my intervention?

NOTE: I don't have access to all the source code right now, so I want to transfer the application "as is" - and not upload the code again to a new server.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google App Engine is an platform to build and run applications and that is out of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com
2. Click *Permissions*
3. Add a member with owner permissions, he'll get an email to approve
4. After approving, he can delete your account.